# how deal with spaces/tabs in txt files

Tags: java, jdbc

i am making a program where i would load data from txt files in mysql tables.I would create tables with specific fields and then I would load the data from the txt files in them. I am using java for doing the program.

What I have written is the below:

```
private static String importData(Connection con, File txtFile,
    String tablename) {

  try {
    Statement stmt;

    stmt = con.createStatement(ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_SENSITIVE,
            ResultSet.CONCUR_UPDATABLE);
    String path = txtFile.getAbsolutePath();
    String importingdata = "LOAD DATA INFILE '"
            + path.replace('\\', '/')
            + "' INTO TABLE " + tablename
            + " FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\t'";
    System.out.println("fill the table");
    stmt.executeUpdate(importingdata);

    } catch (Exception e) {
    System.out.println(((SQLException) e).getSQLState());
    System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    e.printStackTrace();

     }
   return null;
    }
```

But in this code as you can see I has said that the fields are terminated by tab.
What if the columns in the text files are separated by both spaces and tabs with unknown number of them?

For example the text that shown in the image:

[image]

that the first column is separated from the second by one tab and 3 spaces and the second column from the third column by 2 spaces.
All my text files have specific fields but the separated spaces between them is unknown. Is there a way to read all these space until find the next column that contain data?

Comment: Use OpenCSV, it can deal with such data

Comment: No, my purpose is to deal with such files. My program should read such files.

Comment: Well, yes! That is what I say! Use the OpenCSV library and don't bother reinventing the wheel!

Comment: @fge - but the "wheel" is only one line of code ...

Answer (score 3):

There are many ways to do this.  One is to read the file a line at a time, and then split the lines into fields using `String.split(regex)`; e.g.

```
    String line = ...
    String fields[] = line.split("\\s+");
```

Then rewrite the SQL so that you can insert one row at a time.

Or better still, use batches; e.g. as described here: http://viralpatel.net/blogs/batch-insert-in-java-jdbc/

Answer (score 0):

i think you should be specified how your text file contains data either with space or with tab in short there should be some kind of uniformity because sql loader `terminated by`  uses only one argument to identify the column.

Comment: There is not another way for example to read the spaces and tabs until it finds the next collum?

Comment: programatically first read the file replace spaces and tabs with "," and use Terminated by ,